# Assistance with IF and ANDs

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am struggling with the formula shown in the picture. I need to add to the formula so that; IF the E column has the phrase "FD" anywhere in it, the formula will show the phrase "Correct" in the P column.

The E column contains a *large* variety of codes such as 1-FD, 2-FD, 3-FD and so on. There are too many to list in a formula easily. In access I could type in "*" or "?" if I didn't know all the values. How can I do that in an excel formula?

***Edited***: What was suggested from Scott, Vinnie, and Philippe worked:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FD",E2)),O2=T2),"Correct","INCORRECT")
```

However, this still results in "INCORRECT". I have played around with it sightly and have been unable to result in a "Correct" result.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FD", E2))
```

This will return TRUE if cell E2 contains FD.

Edit: Ty scott